# WCF right solution for Publish/subscribe pattern implementation

Tags: c#, wcf

I implemented my own code of Publish/subscribe pattern implementation with WCF with WSDualHttpBinding, but i've a little problem with timeouts that i explain later, for now let me show what i'm doing:

```
public interface IEventSubscriber
{
    [OperationContract]
    void NotifyEvent(EventNotification notification);
    [OperationContract]
    void NotifyServiceDisconnecting();
}

[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(IEventSubscriber))]
public interface IEventPublisherService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, IsInitiating = true)]
    void Subscribe(string culture);
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = true)]
    void Unsubscribe();
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
internal class EventPublisherServiceImpl : IEventPublisherService
{
    ServiceHost host;
    public bool StartService()
    {
        bool ret = false;
        try
        {
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[GlobalConstants.CfgKeyConfigEventPublishserServiceBaseAddress].ToString());
            EventHelper.AddEvent(string.Format("Event Publisher Service on: {0}", baseAddress.ToString()));

            host = new ServiceHost(this, baseAddress);

            // duplex session enable http binding
            WSDualHttpBinding httpBinding = new WSDualHttpBinding(WSDualHttpSecurityMode.None);
            httpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            httpBinding.ReliableSession = new ReliableSession();
            httpBinding.ReliableSession.Ordered = true;
            httpBinding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IEventPublisherService), httpBinding, baseAddress);

            // Enable metadata publishing.
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            // Open the ServiceHost to start listening for messages.
            host.Open();
            ret = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            EventHelper.AddException(e.Message);
        }

        return ret;
    }
 ...

}
```

now in my implementation class i have a list of subscribers that are stored in memory, when a new notification arrived the following code is performed for each subscriber:

```
 ...
    /// <summary>
    /// List of active subscribers
    /// </summary>
    private static Dictionary<IEventSubscriber, string> subscribers = new Dictionary<IEventSubscriber, string>();

 ...
```

that i use it like this:

```
    internal void Subscribe(string culture)
    {
        lock (subscribers)
        {
            // Get callback contract as specified on the service definition
            IEventSubscriber callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IEventSubscriber>();

            // Add subscriber to the list of active subscribers
            if (!subscribers.ContainsKey(callback))
            {
                subscribers.Add(callback, culture);
            }
        }
    }

 ...

    private void OnNotificationEvent(NormalEvent notification)
    {
        lock (subscribers)
        {
            List<IEventSubscriber> listToRemove = new List<IEventSubscriber>();
            //  Method signature: Parallel.ForEach(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> body)
            Parallel.ForEach(subscribers, kvp =>
            {
                try
                {
                    kvp.Key.NotifyEvent(new EventNotification(notification, kvp.Value));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    EventHelper.AddException(string.Format("Error notifying event notification to client: {0} - removing this one", ex.Message));
                    listToRemove.Add(kvp.Key);
                }

            } //close lambda expression
            ); //close method invocation

            Parallel.ForEach(listToRemove, subs =>
            {
                try
                {
                    subs.NotifyServiceDisconnecting();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    EventHelper.AddException(string.Format("Failed to notify client that is to be removed: {0}", 
                        ex.Message));
                }
                subscribers.Remove(subs);
            }
            );
        }
    }
```

What is the problem with this, when timeouts are achieved (note that i set 10 minutes for ReceiveTimeout and inactive timeout) the subscribers that are in the list go to fault state, and the following exception is catched in the **OnNotificationEvent**

**The operation 'NotifyEvent' could not be completed because the sessionful channel timed out waiting to receive a message.  To increase the timeout, either set the receiveTimeout property on the binding in your configuration file, or set the ReceiveTimeout property on the Binding directly. **

Ok i can increase the timeout value, but if i do this it will happen some time, eventually.

My question are: i'm doing something wrong when trying to implement this pattern? or exists any other way of implementing this pattern a better way that avoid this problem? or exist any way of reconnecting the faulted callback channel (for what i'm reading it's not possible, but due to that i can't notify the client that is connection was lost, letting the client blind not knowing that the communication ended!? or is a way to give knowledge that he lost communication with the publisher!?)

Of course solution like ping messages are out of date :) but ok, if nothing better appears look like i've to implement something like that...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now the solution was to change the timeouts to have a infinite value:

```
            // duplex session enable http binding
            WSDualHttpBinding httpBinding = new WSDualHttpBinding(WSDualHttpSecurityMode.None);
            httpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            httpBinding.ReliableSession = new ReliableSession();
            httpBinding.ReliableSession.Ordered = true;
            httpBinding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Parallel.ForEach but I'm not sure that this is enough. AFAIR Parallel.ForEach does not execute each iteration in the separate thread.

I would like to suggest to start separate threads for each subscriber in the OnNotificationEvent and use lock to make sure that foreach will not be breaked by Collection modified exception:

```
lock (_subscribersSync)
         foreach (var chatter in subscribers)
         {
                 Logger.Log.DebugFormat("putting all users to {0}", subscribers.Key.Name);
                 Thread th = new Thread(PublishAllUserMessage);
                 th.Start(new MessageData() { Message = "", Subscriber = chatter.Key};
         }

void PublishAllUserMessage(object messageData)
{
        MessageData md = (MessageData)messageData;
        try
        {
                md.Subscriber.NotifyEvent(...event parameters here ...);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                Logger.Log.Error(string.Format("failed to publish message to '{0}'", md.Subscriber.Name), ex);
                KickOff(md.Subscriber);
        }
}
object _subscribersSync = new object();
void KickOff(IEventSubscriber p)
{
        lock (_subscribersSync)
        {
                subscribers.Remove(p);
                Logger.Log.WarnFormat("'{0}' kicked off", p.Name);
        }
}
 public class MessageData
 {
         public string Message;
         public IEventSubscriber Subscriber;
}
```

Comment: ok, but paralel.ForEach does the same that you do with threads, or similiar, does not create all the threads do a more nice job with that, if i have 2000 clients i don't want to start 2000 threads i'm i right or not?

Comment: AFAIR there is no guarantee that Paralel.ForEach executes each iteration in the separate thread. Yes it looks not so ugly but I've shown a part of code from the working system. You can use ThreadPool instead of creating Thread object. Just try to call subscribers NotifyEvent in separate thread and test how it works for 2k elements. I suppose that timeouts will gone. Also I would like to say that this is cross-process calls and you should remember that a lot of evenets for 2k subscribers can cause your network to be overloaded with Paralel.ForEach or Threads.

Comment: but the timeouts that i was pointing are the ReceiveTimeout and InactivityTimeout not the execution timeout, but ok i will try to do this with threads